# match() textarea value then append words to a div mantaining their original order

Tags: jquery, append, match

I'm trying to do a regex match into a textarea value to extract words, then append them to another div
mantaining the original order.. but the order is not respected..

If I have this in my textarea:

```
<textarea>
http://example.com
http://example.com
http://example.com
</textarea>
```

After apply the match, (match1:`/http/g`) , (match2:`/:\/\//g`), (match3:`/example/g`)
I would like to obtain this:

```
<div id="myDiv">
<span>http</span><span>://</span><span>example.com</span>
<span>http</span><span>://</span><span>example.com</span>
<span>http</span><span>://</span><span>example.com</span>
</div>
```

But I'm using this code:

```
function myFun(eMatch, eType, eClass){
    var split = $('#myTextarea').val().match(eMatch);
    for (var i = 0; i < split.length; i++){
        if(split[i]){
           $('body').append('<'+eType+' class="'+eClass+'">'+split[i]+'</'+eType+'>');
        }
    }
}

myFun(/http/g, "span", "blue");
myFun(/:\/\//g, "span", "green");
myFun(/google/g, "span", "red");
```

And it does not maintain the original order... Is there a way to keep the original order?

**[Here's a JSfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pd4395ej/)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED:**

take a look at this code and see if this is what you want: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pd4395ej/4/)**

```
function myFun(eMatch, eType, eClass,string){
    var split = string.match(eMatch);
    if(split==null) return false;
    for (var i = 0; i < split.length; i++){
        if(split[i]){
            $('body').append('<'+eType+' class="'+eClass+'">'+split[i]+'</'+eType+'>');
        }
    }
}

var lines=$('#myTextarea').val().split(/\n/);
var linesLength=lines.length;
if(typeof lines[linesLength]=='undefined') linesLength--;
var firstVal=$('#myTextarea').val();
$('body').append('<br>');
for(i=0;i<=linesLength;i++){
    myFun(/http/g, "span","blue",lines[i]);
    myFun(/:\/\//g, "span","green",lines[i]);
    myFun(/google/g, "span","red",lines[i]);
    myFun(/.com/g, "span","red",lines[i]);
    $('body').append('<br>')
}
```

you can see that I've changed the logic a bit, you need to pass a string to the function, in order to make it work for elements' texts, values and variables.

what this code does is basically get the value of the textarea line by line, and applies all the replacements to each line, so you get the values in order.

Comment: If I remove the word "google" on the first line, all the following words dont appear.. How can I solve this?

Comment: I get this error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null ", also when just open the fiddles

Comment: here you go http://jsfiddle.net/pd4395ej/3/ you just need to check if the variable `string` is `null`, if it was then `return false`